# I type 'git branch' but it does nothing

Tags: git

I've created a website on Github, and I want to reach it from Git. I cloned it without any problems, but when I use `git branch`, it shows nothing.

I tried `git branch -a` and `git branch -r`, but it does not show anything too.

Also, when I try to checkout to another branch, it says

> error: pathspec 'branch-name' did not match any file(s) known to git.

The output of `git status` is

> On branch master
> No commits yet, and nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: @matt - the output you quoted is not from the `git branch` command.  Maybe make sure you read the question correctly before being ignorant to the person who asked it.

Comment: @matt to be fair "it does nothing" refers to `git branch`, the output of `git status` was added later after I asked for it.

Comment: The local repo is reporting that it contains no commits.  But it sounds like you expect there to be content/history there - in fact, you seem to expect that there's more than one branch to switch to.  So when you say you cloned it without issue... what did you do to clone it?

Answer (score -2):

This means you are yet to create a branch that was created from the master's instance.

Try doing git checkout -b yourBranchName. You should find yourself in the new branch.

Checkout this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvsY1.png)

Comment: By the output of `git status` we can tell that they are inside the Git repository.

Comment: I see, I think that didn't exist when i started commenting. @mkrieger1.

Hence i edited my answer. Hope it works.